# WHy am I getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in forEach with await?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have an object with a series of named SQL query templates that I'm trying to execute.

The query() method is async, so I should be able to run it with await, but I get an Unexpected identifier error. If I take off the await, then I don't get an error, but I'm stuck with a Promise object...

```
Object.entries(sqlquerries).forEach(([queryName, queryTpl]) => {
    try {
        const querystr = replVars(queryTpl, vars);
        report[queryName] = await query(querystr);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('An error occured running the query : ', err );
    }
});
return report;
```

Why would that be? What can I do to construct my report object and get around this error?
Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `forEach(async ([`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the function `await` appears in (the `forEach` callback) isn't an `async` function. If you make it one, beware that `forEach` does nothing with the callback's return value, which will be a promise if it's an `async` function, and so you need to be sure to handle errors inline (which you're doing).

**But**, your `return report` suggests you're expecting to wait for this process to complete. Beware that `forEach` will **not** wait for the previous iteration's promise to resolve before proceeding with the next. If you want to do that, use the promise `reduce` trick instead and `await` the result (I assume this is all in an `async` function):

```
await Object.entries(sqlqueries).reduce((p, [queryName, queryTpl]) => {
    const querystr = replVars(queryTpl, vars);
    return p.then(async() => {
        report[queryName] = await query(querystr);
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
return report;
```

Or if you can run the queries in parallel, use `map` and `Promise.all` instead, and again `await` the result:

```
await Promise.all(Object.entries(sqlqueries).map(async ([queryName, queryTpl]) => {
    const querystr = replVars(queryTpl, vars);
    report[queryName] = await query(querystr);
}));
return report;
```

Comment: Excellent!!! Not only is the answer just what I needed, but the analysis of the situation saved me my next question :-D Thanks loads!!!